# WebMethods binding table data

Tags: business-process-management, webmethods

I have a simple WebMethods user task which has some simple string data and also a document list in the input document. This document list has 4 fields.

The task view has fields for the strings and an aysnc table for the document list to which I have added a 'Add Row' table button.

The problem is the data. Any existing rows that are edited are reflected in the pipeline after the task has been completed but if I add a new row along with values, then the new row is ignored. I have bound the data directly to the table and also tried a content provider to handle the data but neither method passes the updated table data to the output.

Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard,
Try with below options.

1. As the table is getting edited on UI - remove the `sourceArray/sourceList binding of the content provider/ table provider`. (To Populate this provider with list of values,

   - create a new `action`
   - Using data flow implementation assign the provider `sourceArray/sourceList` to the `actual source data list/Array`.
   - Invoke this service before rendering the page (ie., in `Initialize` method if at the loading of page).

2.Change the provider class to "`com.webmethods.caf.faces.data.object.ListTableContentProvider`" manually inside the source code and all respective places. (To verify open bindings view and expand the provider. It should not show the "`Refresh`" action.)

3.On submit form button invoke a action with assigns the provider `sourceArray/sourceList` to the `Target data array/list`.